# Windows unattended.xml install - drive mirroring / software raids

Tags: windows, powershell, unattended

Is it possible to create a mirrored drive (raid 1) via the unattended answers file on Windows Server 2016 ? how?
If not, can it be done with powershell? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **unattended** setup cannot do that. The setup is not (yet) able to manage storage-spaces and/or create dynamic discs in pools.

[update: formating fail]

I *think* it should be possible to do that with post-install scripting, so maybe you try this one:

**Create the mirror'd pool in Powershell**

```
// Write all pooling-avaiable disks in an array ("$PhysicalDisks").
$PhysicalDisks = Get-StorageSubSystem -FriendlyName "Storage Spaces*" | Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True

// Create new storage pool, add the disks
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName ArrayMcPoolface -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Storage Spaces*" -PhysicalDisks $PhysicalDisks

// Add Mirror (Thin Disk)
New-VirtualDisk –FriendlyName ThisIsMyMirrorName -Size <YOUR SIZE IN GB> –StoragePoolFriendlyName ArrayMcPoolface -ProvisioningType Thin

// Online, initialize, create partition, format
Initialize-Disk -VirtualDisk (Get-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName ThisIsMyMirrorName ) -passthru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume
```

More help and documentation on the topic of managing storage: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/?view=win10-ps